# ionic 2 with netbeans keeps showing errors

Tags: netbeans, ionic2, project-management

This might be a superuser question, apologizes if it is.

I keep getting a few errors in netbeans (my IDE) which uses **[typescript](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60605/typescript-editor)** and **[angular2](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/67934/netbeans-angular2-code-templates)** plugins

The errors I'm getting:
[image: picture of two errors]
"Experimental support for decorators is a feature...."
and 
"Cannot find name 'Promise'"

Even though i get these errors, everything works fine. So I'm just looking for a way to remove them showing up, I've read a bit about some ts.config, but I can't find that file..

My project structure looks like this:
[image]

**I've found the ts.config**
It was just not an "important file" I guess ;-)

Though it seems to have no effect:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you install this plugin [link](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/60605/typescript-editor). maybe netbeans can not recognize typescript.

Comment: @aminarghavani that's what i linked to on the "typescript"-link ;-)

Comment: What output do you get when you run `ionic info` ? Lately the projects generated by ionic have a `tsconfig.json` where a boolean is set `experimentalDecorators`. (By the way, Visual Studio Code has the same issue, except the Promise one, even setting the configuration file correctly doesn't resolve it)

Comment: @Ivaro18 Found the TS config file, but seems it is being "ignored"?

Comment: My editor does the same, very annoying but it's an IDE problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently **No solution** to the problem with netbeans plugins.

I've changed to Visual Studio Code, which offers a good typescript compiler.